# SurfFeatureDetector detector(400); SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying use SurfFeatureDetector from opencv to detect keypoints, unfortunately it's not working good. Anyone have idea why?

This is peace of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = imread("C:/Work/Python/in/150903_090428_Image007.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
img2 = imread("C:/Work/Python/in/150903_094605_Image003.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

#detecting keypoints
SurfFeatureDetector detector(400);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
```

And this is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Magda\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Magda\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Work/Python/in/Images_manipulation_v3.py", line 9
    SurfFeatureDetector detector(400);
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I am working with OpenCV 2.4.9, Visual Studio 2013,|Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit) with Python 2.7.10, Windows 10.

Comment: It seems that you're mixing python and C++ code...

Comment: @Miki it could be :) I just start working with programming. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Check [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html) how it should be done in python